# MySQL Workbench 6.0 and Windows 8 - Failed to connect to MySql at localhost?

Tags: mysql, windows-8, mysql-workbench

I am simply lost as to where this problem is originating from or why the Workbench is acting the way it is. My system is Windows 8 running MySQL Workbench 6.0. I setup new connection and the user is root, host is localhost and connection method - standard TCP/IP. Everything else is left as it is. I click on Test connection button and I get **Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root** Even if I ignore that error and simply create the connection by click on OK button, it asks for password when I click on the connection to open the connection. I even uninstalled and re-installed Workbench as many has suggested in Stackoverflow and other websites. My server is running (mysql.exe).

What's weird is that on Windows 7, Workbench doesn't have any problem. Test connection work as expected.

Comment: Is the MySQL service running?

Comment: Please upgrade to Workbench 6.2.x before proceeding, and view this useful MySQL connection related video -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY

Comment: @PhilipOlson I just noticed that I did install 6.2 CE Workbench, but when I click on HELP->About WorkBench it says 6.0 . Actually I have been watching this Youtube video and have not been much of a help.

Comment: @ThN It sounds like you have multiple Workbench installations, so this is worth investigating. Also, can you connect to MySQL via the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue. I simply uninstalled MySQL from my system. Then, I reinstalled MySQL through Windows Platform Installer. Also, re-installed MySQL Workbench. That was it. Now, my PHP files are able to talk to the database without any problem. Plus, MySQL workbench as well working as expected.